# Understanding the colon in ASP.NET Core configurations?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

It's frustrating the relationship between JSON files and configuration in ASP.NET Core.
I have set a secret like this:

```
dotnet user-secrets set "Pwd" "123"
```

It seems like there's no way to retrive it through `IConfiguration.GetSection` method, only `IConfiguration.GetValue` can be used, I need to use `IConfiguration.GetSection` to bind the value with a POCO object :

```
public class AppSecrets
{
    public int Pwd { get; set; }
}
```

I then added another secret: `"parent:pwd" "456"`
And looked at the auto-generated JSON file and it looks like a regular JSON with two key:

```
{
  "Pwd": "123",
  "parent:pwd": "456"
}
```

so what makes the colon special for the configuration in .NET Core. In [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows)
they mentioned:

> In the preceding example, the colon denotes that Movies is an object
>   literal with a ServiceApiKey property.

But in my example the value was retrieved despite the `parent` doesnt map to the AppSecrets class by name.

Also another point frustrating me the way values are passed to the application arguments in the project properties, something like this:

```
--user:data:year 1991
```

can we pass more hierarchical nodes?

sorry for frustrating you by my frustration. I'm just discoveering the .NET core!

Comment: colon syntax is how you express hierarchy for storing config in user secrets or environment variables. regular json used in appsettings.json can naturally express the hierarchy. For poco settings you typically configure it from a section and then the poco can be injected anywhere it is needed, you don't need to access it from config.

Comment: So can we write a JSON like this: `{"key":"val", "par":{"key1":"val1"}}` in the colon syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a poco class for smtp settings:

```
public class SmtpOptions
{
   public string Server { get; set; }
   public int Port { get; set; } = 25;
   public string User { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; } 
   public string DefaultEmailFromAddress { get; set; }
 }
```

You can put that in appsettings.json like this:

```
{
"SmtpOptions": {
    "Server": "MyServer",
    "Port": "25",
    "User": "MyUser",
    "Password": "MyPassword",
    "DefaultEmailFromAddress": "noreply@mydomain"
    }
  }
```

Register it like this and now that poco can be injected anywhere.

```
services.Configure<SmtpOptions>(configuration.GetSection("SmtpOptions"));
```

If you want to make that in user secrets you need multiple commands and colon syntax like this:

```
dotnet user-secrets set "SmtpOptions:Server" "MyServer"
dotnet user-secrets set "SmtpOptions:Port" "25"
dotnet user-secrets set "SmtpOptions:User" "MyUser"
dotnet user-secrets set "SmtpOptions:Password" "MyPassword"
dotnet user-secrets set "SmtpOptions:DefaultEmailFromAddress" "noreply@mydomain"
```

The colons express the hierarchy in a way that is possible from the command line, so that syntax can be used to set user secrets or environment variables, creating the same hierarchy as the json.

Comment: The `secrets.json` file generated by the command `dotnet user-secrets` also supports nested objects if i remember correctly. Therefore a copy of `appsettings.json` smtpoptions block with correct items will overwrite the settings aswell. One can easily edit the `secrets.json` within visual studio by right clicking the project and click `Manage user secrets`

Comment: I understand that ASP.NET can deal with the colon the way you explained. but way the JSON file generated isn't like the JSON example you provided, I tried it and it's: `{  "SmtpOptions:User": "MyUser", //etc`

Comment: I would not worry about what the secrets file looks like. The code I showed achieves the same configuration hierarchy and can bind the same poco object.